# use api response in FlSpot() instead of numbers flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, fl-chart

I'm trying to draw a line graph from API responses in flutter with fl_chart.
In this section;

```html
spots: [
                                                      const FlSpot(0, 1.4),
                                                      const FlSpot(4, 1.5),
                                                      const FlSpot(8, 1.6),
                                                    ],
```

[image]
instead of numbers, I want to use my api responses :

```html
  final String? sondeger;
  final String? mindeger;
  final String? maxdeger;




  const StocksDetailScreen({
    Key? key,
     this.sondeger,
     this.mindeger,
     this.maxdeger,



  }) : super(key: key);
```

How can I use my API responses instead of numbers?

Comment: If it's needed, I can add more codes from the page, just ask, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed const :

```html
spots: [
                                                      FlSpot(0, widget.min!),
                                                      FlSpot(4, widget.max!),
                                                      FlSpot(8, widget.son!),
                                                    ],
```